# How to pass the sqlite query after database screation in that script..?

Tags: mysql, sqlite

```
#!/bin/bash

echo " --- Enter the Database name ---"
read databasename

sqlite3 $databasename.db 


echo " --- Enter the Table details --- "

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER_DETAILS(cus_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,cus_name TEXT NOT NULL,cus_domain TEXT UNIQUE, cus_status TEXT NOT NULL,Port INTEGER NOT NULL);


#echo " --- Enter the total number of customer records ---"
read cus_count

for((i=0;i<=cus_count;i++))
do
read c_name
read c_domain
read c_status
read port

INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_DETAILS(cus_name,cus_domain,cus_status) VALUES(\"$c_name\",\"$c_domain\",\"$c_status\",\"$port\");

done

#echo " --- select the records from the table ---"

select * from CUSTOMER_DETAILS;
```

once i execute this script in terminal ./demo_example.sh the script will be execute until the database creation only .after that it will struct in sqlite> the query not pass to the sqlite .please help me how can i pass the sqlite query using command line in script[my output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJHQV.png)

Comment: I answerd, but I have some comments too: you insert have problems, because you inserted 4 elements to 3 fields. your script doesnt tell which input is waiting for, and it must check that the port is integer

Comment: In addition, pay attention to the change I made in `create table`, I added `if not exists` that would prevent re-creating the table if it exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use non-interactive mode by passing the query in the command line:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo " --- Enter the Database name ---"
read databasename


echo " --- Enter the Table details --- "

sqlite3 $databasename.db  "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CUSTOMER_DETAILS(cus_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,cus_name TEXT NOT NULL,cus_domain TEXT UNIQUE, cus_status TEXT NOT NULL,Port INTEGER NOT NULL);"


#echo " --- Enter the total number of customer records ---"
read cus_count

for((i=0;i<=cus_count;i++))
do
read c_name
read c_domain
read c_status
read port

sqlite3 $databasename.db "INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_DETAILS(cus_name,cus_domain,cus_status, Port) VALUES(\"$c_name\",\"$c_domain\",\"$c_status\",\"$port\");"

done

#echo " --- select the records from the table ---"

sqlite3 $databasename.db "select * from CUSTOMER_DETAILS;"
```

Comment: Thank you ...@Tamar

Comment: i have another one dought .if i use one column as a unique constraint .then i repeat the same value one more time on that time i want to an printing statement like as "This customer name is already available !please enter the new customer name " where i define and how i define in that script.please help me

Comment: you can either select the name and if there is result not enter it, or add unique constraint to the table and check for error when inserting, or use `INSERT OR IGNORE`

Comment: how i define the printing statement..?